# how can I convert horizontal bars into responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a horizontal bar that has 4 items or maybe more. What I am trying to do is that when the browser is resized each item of the horizontal bar with its respective element, however, I am using  twitter-bootstrap 4, but it doesn't seem to work either by default

```css
.post-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.flex7 {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.flex7-child-1 {
    height: 40%;
    position: relative;
}

.flex7-child-1:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50.png');
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    top: -60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.flex7-child-2:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50.png);
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    top: 88px;
    left: -170px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 24px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.flex7-child-3:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50.png);
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    top: 85px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.flex7-child-4:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50.png);
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    top: 85px;
    left: 170px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 106px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.flex7-child-5:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50.png);
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    top: 58px;
    left: 166px;
    right: -174px;
    margin: 106px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.flex7-child {
    width: 14%;
}
.child {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #A2CBFA;
    border: 1px solid #4390E1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,90,250,0.05), 0 4px 4px rgba(0,90,250,0.05), 0 8px 8px rgba(0,90,250,0.05), 0 16px 16px rgba(0,90,250,0.05);
}

.flex7-child-2 {
    height: 50%;
}
.flex7-child-3 {
    height: 60%;
}

.flex7-child-4 {
    height: 20%;
}

.flex7-child-5 {
    height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-content-wrapper">
  <div class="flex flex7">
    <div class="child flex7-child flex7-child-1"></div>
    <div class="child flex7-child flex7-child-2"></div>
    <div class="child flex7-child flex7-child-3"></div>
    <div class="child flex7-child flex7-child-4"></div>
    <div class="child flex7-child flex7-child-5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

before toggle

[image: before]

after toggle, I am expecting to have the same position even when I resize the layout without breaking the elements

[image: after]

Comment: What toggle are you referring to?

Comment: the bars from the sidebar menu, but basically, how can I keep the same position element even when I resize?

Comment: I would recommend changing how you structure this. Each bar should be in a wrapper element with it's thumbnail to insure they position correctly. I'll post an answer with an example.

Comment: sure, I would like to see an example how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better way to achieve responsive consistent styles for your horizontal bars. Note that individual styles for each `.flex7-child-#:before` has been removed, and all `.flex7-child` elements now use flexbox.

```
.post-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.flex7 {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Pay attention to below */

.flex7-child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
.flex7-child:before {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50.png');
    background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center center;
    top: -70px;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

/* Pay attention to above */

.flex7-child {
    width: 14%;
}
.child {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #A2CBFA;
    border: 1px solid #4390E1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,90,250,0.05), 0 4px 4px rgba(0,90,250,0.05), 0 8px 8px rgba(0,90,250,0.05), 0 16px 16px rgba(0,90,250,0.05);
}
.flex7-child-1 {
    height: 40%;
}
.flex7-child-2 {
    height: 50%;
}
.flex7-child-3 {
    height: 60%;
}

.flex7-child-4 {
    height: 20%;
}

.flex7-child-5 {
    height: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact example, but I would wrap your thumbnails and bars together something like this:

```css
#container{
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid gainsboro;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.flex-item > .bar{
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.flex-item:after{
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/80.png")
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="bar" style="height:40%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="bar" style="height:20%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="bar" style="height:60%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="bar" style="height:50%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="bar" style="height:70%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```